# Set style of internal element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having difficulty referring to the element inside an anchor. The ???? part of this is where I'm struggling.

```
<a href='#' onclick="????.style.display='inline';return false;"><img src='hello.jpg' style='display:none;'/>SHOW IMAGE</a>
```

In case it isn't obvious, I want the image to show if you click on SHOW IMAGE. Referring to the first child inside of "this" isn't working in any form that I've been able to think of.

Comment: "Referring to the first child inside of "this" isn't working in any form that I've been able to think of" — It works in the simplest form of that when I try it. How about showing the failing code and telling us what errors you get rather then putting a bunch of `?` that are guaranteed to error?

Comment: Please paste your js code as well.

Comment: Please ask a real, demonstrative, question with real, representative, code.

Comment: I am an idiot. There is a scriptblocker on this computer (not MY computer). No matter how many times I click on the link, javascript doesn't work. So, fistChild, childNodes[0], writing a completely separate function to get the first child... nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. You get the first child node of "this".

```
<a href='#' onclick="this.childNodes[0].style.display='inline';return false;"><img src='hello.jpg' style='display:none;'/>SHOW IMAGE</a>
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pb64rfsv/